# PHP/Javascript/Python not reloading div

Tags: javascript, php, python, html, forms

I am using a raspberry pi to pulse a relay (on the below form submit) to another piece of equipment which if successfully pulsed will toggle a relay on/off.  The toggled relay comes back to the pi as an input which is being monitored on the status.php page inside of the loading div.  If I load the below page, it correctly displays the status.php, but after pressing the form submit button, it does not reload the status.php page.  I have tried everything I can think of, please help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Alarm Panel</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
     $(document).ready(function() {
                    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
     setInterval(function() {
     $('#loading').load('/status.php');
     }, 2000);
     });
// ]]>
</script>
  <?php
     if (isset($_POST['PULSE'])) {
            shell_exec('python /usr/lib/cgi-bin/pulse.py');
        }
  ?>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="currentstatus" data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="b" data-collapsed="false">
     <h1>Current status</h1>
     <div id="loading" align="center">
        <H3>Loading Status...</H3>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="b">
     <h4>Change Status</h4>
     <form method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="PULSE" value="PULSE" />
     </form>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

status.php
    `<?php
    $status = shell_exec('python /usr/lib/cgi-bin/status.py'); 
    ?>
    <h3><? echo $status; ?></h3>
    <br />
    <img src="/img/<? print $status; ?>.jpg" height="250"; width="250";>`

Comment: have you tried setting the form's `action='?'` ? It seems like the form isn't submitting to it's parent doc...

Comment: lol. I think that may be irrelevant, actually. let me try for a real solution...

Comment: What's in status.php?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried manipulating submit behavior? that may fix it.

```
$(document).on('click', '[name="pulse"]', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#loading').load('/status.php');
});
```

you may also try changing your timeout function... That's a bit tricky because load is an asynchronous function.

```
var loadStatusTimeout;
function loadStatus() {
     $('#loading').load('/status.php', function() {
         loadStatusTimeout = setTimeout(loadStatus, 2000);
     });
}
loadStatusTimeout = setTimeout(loadStatus, 2000);
```

also, you're accidentally adding semicolons into your img element:

change:

```
<img src="/img/<? print $status; ?>.jpg" height="250"; width="250";>
```

to:

```
<img src="/img/<? print $status; ?>.jpg" height="250" width="250">
```

Comment: I tried adding this in the same script tag as the document.ready but it still did not work correctly after submit. The post of pulse still works, just not the refresh of loading.

Comment: Thanks I removed the semicolon.  
I changed the load script to the following with no avail
 `<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
         var loadStatusTimeout;
         function loadStatus() {
              $('#loading').load('/status.php', function() {
                  loadStatusTimeout = setTimeout(loadStatus, 2000);
              });
         }
         loadStatusTimeout = setTimeout(loadStatus, 2000);
         // ]]>
      </script>`

I also then tried adding 
      `echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
                   , 'loadstatus();'
                   , '</script>';`

Comment: Sorry - details would help. I added the loadstatus(); function call to the section containing isset($_POST['PULSE']))

Comment: I also tried making a copy of the file and adding action="index-2.php" on index.php and vice versa.  It didnt even load the status on correctly on changing pages.  Only on inital page load or a forced F5 refresh.